# Fourier series representation for $\sin(x/2)$

Tags: fourier-series

Is there a faster approach for finding the Fourier series of $$\sin(x/2)~,\cos(x/2)~~~\text{etc}$$
other than the usual approach?

Comment: Fourier series generally apply to period function a period $2\pi$. These are not quite so periodic. You could define though a function equal to these on the interval $[0,2\pi]$, and define for periodicity outside that interval.

Comment: The usual approach is pretty fast, isn't it? You have to calculate integrals like $\int\sin nx\sin(x/2)\,dx$, and you can use trig identities to transform that product of sines into a simple sum, which sum is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 5):

I'll give a non-standard derivation for $\cos (x/2)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Faster or not, you tell.

The function being even,  we work with cosines. Observe   that if $$f(x)\sim \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos nx\tag1$$ then
$$f''(x)\sim -\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 a_n \cos nx\tag2$$ 
I am writing $\sim $ instead of $=$ here  to avoid getting arrested by the 
convergence police. Naturally, we want to plug (1) and (2) into $f''= (-1/4)f$ and equate coefficients. This does not work.

The problem is, $f''$ is not exactly $(-1/4)f$. The values of $f'$ at the endpoints don't match, and this
discontinuity contributes a point mass to $f''$. The correct formula is $$f''=(-1/4)f+\delta_{\pi}+\delta_{-\pi}\tag3$$ 
It's easy to find the coefficients for the delta function:
$$\delta_\pi +\delta_{-\pi}= \frac{c_0}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\cos nx, \quad c_n= (-1)^n\frac{2}{\pi}\tag4$$
because "integrating"  against a delta function amounts to evaluation.  Now plug into (3).
$$-n^2 a_n = (-1/4)a_n +  c_n\tag5$$
which yields
$$ a_n = \frac{-c_n}{n^2-1/4}\tag6$$
with $c_n$ as in (4).

Comment: Convergence police *is* a good term. Also, why not substitute the number $\tfrac{1}{2}$ in $\cos{(x/2)}$ with a general $k$.

Comment: @Nick One could do that, although the easy case of integer $k$ must be treated separately. I "leave this as an exercise for the interested reader."